# MongoDB: Select all polygons within the radius of a point

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have two collections in my database: Post and Gallery.  A Post has a single GeoJSON Point location, and a gallery is a collection of posts.  The gallery's location is a GeoJSON Polygon bounding the gallery's posts (using quickhull algorithm).  I now need to query for all galleries within x miles of a certain point, however I'm not getting any results even if I query from right next to my polygon.

I would like the behavior to be exactly the same as the following:

```
db.posts.find({
    'location': {
        $geoWithin: {
            $centerSphere: [[-70, 30], 1000/3959]
        }
    }
});
```

Here, all posts within a the radius are returned.  However, when I run the same type of function in this way, I am returned nothing, which is not correct:

```
db.galleries.find({
    'location': {
        $geoWithin: {
            $centerSphere: [[-70, 30], 1000/3959]
        }
    }
});
```

One of my galleries has the following location (is 2dsphere index with `2dsphereIndexVersion = 2`):

```
"location": {
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        -73.986882,
        40.682829
      ],
      [
        -73.971089,
        40.6672045
      ],
      [
        -73.955296,
        40.65158
      ],
      [
        -73.986882,
        40.682829
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

How do I query for location polygons that at least intersect with my radius?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I thought that changing `$geoWithin` to `$geoIntersects` would do the trick but that didn't work either. I'll update you if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried the exact same query that you initially tried. I'm not sure why it didn't work, but I was eventually able to get [$near](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/near/#op._S_near) to do the job. Keep in mind that $near uses meters when calculating $maxDistance, so I had to convert my 10 mile desired distance to meters by multiplying by 1609.34. Here's the query that I ended up using:

```
db.maTowns.find(
    {
        'geometry': {
            $near: {
                $geometry: {
                    'type': "Point",
                    'coordinates': [ -71, 42 ]                                    
                },
                $maxDistance: 10 * 1609.34
             }
         }
     }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Select all polygons within the radius of a point

With the recent release of MongoDB version `3.6.0-rc0`, you can now query GeoJSON LineStrings and Polygons with [$geoWithin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) geospatial operator [$centerSphere](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/).

See also [SERVER-27968](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27968) for more information about the change. Note that this change is pending to be backported.

Also maybe related for `$geoIntersects` and `$centerSphere` is ticket [SERVER-30390](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30390)